# shell command to restart an php program

Tags: php, shell

I need to restart my php program when the memory of the program exceeds 500mb.
Can it be done by any script in php or in shell?

Comment: Is this Windows shell or something like Bash or ksh?

Comment: Is this a hack to get around a memory leak?

Comment: Proper action would indeed be freeing memory so to stay under 500MB, no restart required.

Answer (score 1):

Run your PHP script like this:

```
php -d "memory_limit=500M" myscript.php
```

And do it forever:

```
while true; do php -d "memory_limit=500M" myscript.php; done
```

Comment: heh... good trick :)
I would use daemon for this...

Comment: i have written an shell script start.sh like this
php -d "memory_limit=500M" myscript.php
while true; do php -d "memory_limit=500M" myscript.php; done
once i run the program i am getting segmentation fault error....

Comment: @Ram, The script should only contain the second line.  I was just showing the natural progression to the solution in my answer.  I don't see how you would get a segfault; this would be a bug in PHP which you may want to report.  (How are you normally executing the PHP script?)

Comment: @strager ,it didnt restart the program the memory is still increasing.... if i use 
"while true; do php -d "memory_limit=500M" myscript.php; done"

Comment: @Ram, When PHP reaches the memory limit, it raises a fatal error and quits the PHP script.  Are you absolutely sure PHP is using more than 500MB?

Comment: How does your PHP script hit 500 MB of memory usage so quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I deal with long-running programs, I like to include some basic tools for checking whether they are active, what errors they are creating, etc.  Here's a quick script I run with cron to make sure that my gearman workers are running.

```
$program = 'program.php';  

// Run the cmd to get list of running programs  
exec( "ps aux | grep $program | awk '{print $12}'", $output );  

if( count($output) == 0 )  
    exec( "php $program > /dev/null &" );
```

Of course, you may not want the output of your script sent to /dev/null.  In fact, if you're having problems with memory usage, you may want to use the `>>` operator to capture your script's output in a makeshift log.